# Tried to split wchar or another function to get the file name of running application

Tags: c++, arrays, string, split, char

I searched here a lot and did try several examples but still can't solve my little problem.
I need to extract the file name 'test.exe' out of the path. Has someone an idea which might work? Other option is to get the file name by another function?

Thanks in advance!

```c
WCHAR fileName[255];

GetModuleFileName(NULL, fileName, 255);   // fileName = \TestFolder\test.exe
```

Comment: Find the end of the string, work backwards to the start until you hit the first `\\`, and that will give you the range the file name takes up.

Comment: `_wsplitpath` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/splitpath-wsplitpath?view=msvc-160

Comment: or [std::filesystem::path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path).

Comment: Can you add an example? Your ideas sound easy in theory but still doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`PathFindFileName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathfindfilenamew):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")

WCHAR fullPath[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, fullPath, MAX_PATH);
LPWSTR fileName = PathFindFileName(fullPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using WinApi**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

std::string GetExecutableName()
{
    std::string path = std::string(MAX_PATH, 0);
    if( !GetModuleFileNameA(nullptr, &path[0], MAX_PATH ) )
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(u8"Error at get executable name."); 
    }
    size_t pos=path.find_last_of('/');
    if(pos == std::string::npos)
    {
        pos = path.find_last_of('\\');
    }
    return path.substr(pos+1);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<< GetExecutableName() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Using main args**

First - arg[0] contains full filename of executable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string GetExecutableName(const std::string& exe)
{
    size_t pos=exe.find_last_of('/');
    if(pos == std::string::npos)
    {
        pos =exe.find_last_of('\\');
    }
    return exe.substr(pos+1);
}

int main(int argc,char ** args) {
    std::cout << GetExecutableName(args[0])<< std::endl;
}
```